# How do I get the remote address of a client in WebRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

Is there any way that I could get the original IP address of the client coming to the server from `org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest` ?

Comment: Be aware that this will be the IP address currently assigned to the last device that forwarded the request. Not necessarily the client and certainly unsuitable for use as a session key or authentication principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at the hierarchy where this interface is used.
Here's the UML:
[image: UML Diagram]
Main thing here is to find the place where we will be able to get the native `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` interface and its standard methods:
`getRemoteAddr()`, `getRemotePort()`, `getRemoteHost()`.